# When I am installing eksctl in my wsl-ubuntu I am getting this error like unexcepected end of file

Tags: devops, amazon-eks

```
giri@DESKTOP-36R4CJ8:~$ curl -sL "https://github.com/eksctl-io/eksctl/releases/latest/download/eksctl_checksums.txt" | grep $PLATFORM | sha256sum --check
```

> eksctl_Linux_amd64.tar.gz: FAILED
> sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

```
giri@DESKTOP-36R4CJ8:~$ tar -xzf eksctl_$PLATFORM.tar.gz -C /tmp && rm eksctl_$PLATFORM.tar.gz
```

> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
> tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I used the commands that provided above and I am getting the error like endoffile.

I just need to install eksctl in wsl-ubuntu.. that's it